# SoLR performance issue

Tags: solr, lucene, jetty

I am working on solr 4.2.1 jetty and we are facing some performance issues and heap memory overflow issue as well.

So I am searching the actual cause for this exceptions. Then i applied load test for different solr queries. After few mins got below errors:

> WARN:oejs.Response:Committed before 500 {msg=Software caused
>   connection abort: socket write
>
> Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort:
>   socket write error
>
> SEVERE: null:org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException

I also tried to set the maxIdleTime to 300000 milliSeconds. But still getting same error.

Any ideas? 
Please help, how to tackle this.

Thanks,
Mayur

### Stack Trace:

> SEVERE: null:org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.flushBuffer(HttpGenerator.java:914)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.http.AbstractGenerator.blockForOutput(AbstractGenerator.java:507)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:147)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:107)
>           at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(Unknown Source)
>           at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.solr.util.FastWriter.flush(FastWriter.java:141)
>           at org.apache.solr.util.FastWriter.write(FastWriter.java:55)
>           at org.apache.solr.response.XMLWriter.writePrim(XMLWriter.java:356)
>           at org.apache.solr.response.XMLWriter.writeStr(XMLWriter.java:295)
>           at org.apache.solr.schema.StrField.write(StrField.java:67)
>           at org.apache.solr.response.TextResponseWriter.writeVal(TextResponseWriter.java:130)
>           at org.apache.solr.response.XMLWriter.writeSolrDocument(XMLWriter.java:199)
>           at org.apache.solr.response.TextResponseWriter.writeDocuments(TextResponseWriter.java:275)
>           at org.apache.solr.response.TextResponseWriter.writeVal(TextResponseWriter.java:172)
>           at org.apache.solr.response.XMLWriter.writeResponse(XMLWriter.java:111)
>           at org.apache.solr.response.XMLResponseWriter.write(XMLResponseWriter.java:39)
>           at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.writeResponse(SolrDispatchFilter.java:627)
>           at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:358)
>           at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:141)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1307)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:453)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:560)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1072)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:382)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1006)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:365)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:485)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:926)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:988)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:635)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket
>   write error
>           at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
>           at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ByteArrayBuffer.writeTo(ByteArrayBuffer.java:359)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.io.bio.StreamEndPoint.flush(StreamEndPoint.java:164)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.io.bio.StreamEndPoint.flush(StreamEndPoint.java:194)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.flushBuffer(HttpGenerator.java:838)
>           ... 46 more

Comment: Full stacktrace? Did you just run out of memory, i.e. is there a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError exception in your logs?

Comment: Please see stack trace, i edited above question.

Comment: Are you sure your load test clients are actually waiting for the response? It looks to me like they're disconnecting before getting the response.